# Problema con input en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

Buenas. Estoy creando una función que recibe dos parámetros. Una función tan sencilla que lleva a cabo el proceso de suma de dos números. Pero al momento de ir a consola cuando pido los números tengo que usar dos input . uno para el primer numero y el otro para el segundo y luego se suma y se retorna el resultado. Pero quiero hacerlo algo mas estético y me preguntaba si había una forma de hacer algo tipo un input que en la misma línea me permitiera ingresar dos valores separados por un signo mas . algo así `(numero1) + (numero2)` y poder ingresar los valores en la misma linea . hay alguna manera ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo de "estético" es muy relativo, y en general es preferible evaluar otros elementos como performance, mantenibilidad, seguridad o legibilidad antes que el código se vea bonito. Dicho esto, veamos algunas posibilidades:

La forma tradicional de definir una función que recibe dos parámetros. Si el requerimiento es que debe sumar dos valores numéricos, está es la forma adecuada de definir una función:

```
def sumar(valor1, valor2):
  return valor1 + valor2

print(sumar(1,2))
```

Eventualmente podríamos rediseñar la función para que acepte más de un valor mediante el uso de parámetros variables:

```
def sumar1(*valores):
  return sum([v for v in valores])

print(sumar1(1,2))
print(sumar1(1,2,3,4))
```

En este ejemplo `[v for v in valores]` es una técnica llamada "comprensión de listas", básicamente: *"crear una lista por cada elemento del iterable `valores`"*. Por último aplicamos [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum) a la lista.

Esta otra opción puede ser la respuesta a tu pregunta, la idea es pasar 2 o más valores separados por `+`, claramente para hacer esto, debemos pasar una cadena, veamos:

```
def sumar2(valores):
  return sum([int(v) for v in valores.split("+")])

print(sumar2("1+3+4"))
```

No es del todo raro tener que hacer esto, muchas veces recibiremos "cadenas" de caracteres desde otros programas, APIs, interfaces, etc. y deberemos hacer algo como lo expuesto. En primer lugar "separamos" los valores por el caracter `+` mediante [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split), que es un método propio de cualquier cadena, con el mismo obtendremos un conjunto de caracteres que representan  números, a cada uno de estos valores lo convertimos a entero mediante [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int) y todo lo transformamos en una lista mediante "comprensión de listas", por último aplicamos la función [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum) que suma la lista completa.

Y por último y solo como dato anecdótico ya que no deberíamos usarlo a menos que tengamos absoluta seguridad sobre el input. Disponemos de [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval) el cual permite justamente evaluar una cadena Python, en el ejemplo retornamos la evaluación de "1+3+4".

```
def sumar3(valores):
  return eval(valores)

print(sumar3("1+3+4"))
```

Es una forma muy flexible por que podríamos evaluar distintas cosas como `1/2 * 3^2` o también cosa peligrosas como `sumar("__import__('os').system('ls .')")`.

Espero te sea útil.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos te propongo dos posibles soluciones, una la que te mencionan Patricio sobre usar split la otra usando expresiones regulares simples.

Con esta solucion la entrada debe ser-> 3 + 4 Salida -> 'Valor 1: 3, Valor 2: 4'

```
valores=input('Entra los dos valores separados por - >')
list_valor = valores.split('+')
print ('Valor 1: %s, Valor 2: %s' % (list_valor[0], list_valor[1]))
```

Una psoible solución con expresiones simples te permitiría entrar los números que quiera separados por ()
Entrada -> (2)(3) Salida-> ['2', '3']

```
import re

patron = re.compile('(\d+)')
print(patron.findall(valores))
```